# On vCenter setting in vcdb.properties , what does it mean by 'usevcdb = true'

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

VMware KB is very complicated and not enough. I'm very confused.

I had migrated the database from bundled SQLServer Express to Standard. I've followed KB1028601 , which is for migrating database and includes another KB1021202. Followed the linked [KB1021202](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1021202), an entry in vcdb.properties should be commented.

> 2.Comment this line in the file:
>
> usevcdb=true

Does anyone know what is it for that the entry usevcdb is not true? It's very odd not to use VCDB, which is the only database for the vCenter services. Is it a misprint? 'Comment' means to use this line? I'm not confident because I'm not native.

I'm using v5.1.

EDIT:
[KB2001363](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/2001363) says  the storage view of vSphere needs the setting.

Comment: What KB, what database.... and, just in general, what?  (`vcdb` stands for vCenter Database, however, and coupled with the word "true", I'd guess you're telling... whatever... to *use* the *vcdb* database.)

Comment: 1028601 is migration, and it includes another KB 1021202, for which you should comment ' usevcdb =true '. That means not to use VCDB? Its odd. The only database vcenter using.

Answer (score -1):

*sigh* go to C:\ProgramData\VMware\VMware VirtualCenter, then open the file vcdb.properties, edit it, save it, restart the services.

Comment: thnx. but i want to know of the meaning , and how does it work?